# Porting and running a simple Qt Program to FriendlyARM-embedded devices

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qmake, qtgui

As you know, the major source for downloading QT is 
  http://qt-project.org/downloads.

Before Qt 5.0, there was a link for Qt for Embedded Linux, for example:
  qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5.tar.gz

I assumed it's somehow a replacement for Qtopia. Also, I assumed the 'everywhere' means 'embedded'.
Are my assumptions correct?

If my assumptions are right, is it OK to use the above everywhere version instead of old Qtopia?

another problem is: I configured the Qtopia to build libraries statically (using default -shared) then I built it and installed it successfully.

Now I at host computer I have Qtopia 4.3.5 embedded ARM software at the following default path:
/usr/local/Trolltech/QtopiaCore4.3.5embedded-arm

Q: Why there are no designer program at /bin directory.

I just have the following binaries:
moc, qmake, rcc, uic
then I wrote a typical hello world Qt with QApplication and QLabel classes:

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QLabel>

    int main(argc, char* argv[])
    {
       QApplication app(argc, argv);
       QLabel Hello("Hello");
       Hello.show();
       return app.exec();  
    }
```

I compiled this code with newly installed qmake and it's totally OK.
If the name of binary is qt_hello, I have the following output:

# file qt_hello

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1(SYSV), dynamically linked (use shared libs),
  for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped

Now, when I port the binary to ARM embedded device board (using flash disk USB),
and run it, I have the following output:

# ./qt_hello
error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.

based on error message, I guess, I should configure tries to configure Qtopia again with -static option. I used the following
command:
`./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -depths 16,3 -nomake examples

    -nomake tests -static`
after a couple of hours, the software was configured, built and installed successfully,
after qmaking my hello program, unfortunately it's linked shared and I had above errors
on ARM embedded device?

Am I miss something? Please shed some light.

FYI, the Qtopia4.6.3 is installed on the ARM Embedded device

-- Saeed Amrollahi Boyouki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two radically different things in here:

- Very old Qtopia
- Old 4.8.5

As suggested [in your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919523/c-qt-arm-processors-cross-compiling-programming), using 5.2.0 would be more adequate a task for this. That being said, let me reply to your questions:

> If my assumptions are right, is it OK to use the above everywhere version instead of old Qtopia?

Yes, that is right.

> Q: Why there are no designer program at /bin directory.

I think you have to install that separately from the Qt libraries, just like QtCreator.

> ./qt_hello error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.

It means you do not have the qt gui dynamic library on your embedded board in the library path which is the system-wide by default where Qt is usually installed.

> after a couple of hours, the software was configured, built and installed successfully, after qmaking my hello program, unfortunately it's linked shared and I had above errors on ARM embedded device? Am I miss something? Please shed some light.

I think you forgot to link against the Qt library statically. For instance, try to specify the static library explicitly in your project's qmake project file as follows:

```
LIBS += libQtGui.a # cannot recall the name correctly, but it is easy to check
```

Comment: Laszlo I added the above line but during making project, compiler issues error: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++: libQtGui.a: no such file or directory.

Comment: @SaeedAmrollahiBoyouki: have you checked if you have such a file in your library path and/or the current working directory where the linkage happens to be?

Comment: Laszlo Papp: Yes I have several such files: libQtGui.{a|.la|.prl| .so|.so.4|.so.4.3|.so.4.3.5|} the .so, .so.4, .so.4.3 are symlink to the last one. They are at <QT PREFIX DIRECTOR>/lib directory. BTW, if I run ldconfig -p, there is no entry for above files, but I have just one entry: libQtGui.so.4 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i365-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4. Q. How to add <QT>/lib to library path?

Comment: @SaeedAmrollahiBoyouki: LIBS += -L<QT PREFIX DIRECTOR>/lib libQtGui.a

Comment: Again, I faced to original error. FYI, if I use lower-case L, and <QT PREFIX DIR>/lib/libQtGui.a, I'll face with this error: arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find libQtGui.a that based on -l vs. -L applications is reasonable.

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong. -L/path -lQtGui should just work if you do not have dynamic libraries in the path which you should not based on your scenario.